# Data annotation validation for multiple model properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I'm currently using MVC data annotations for validating my form and it looks quite easy.

Now, I have a particular situation:

IF(checkbox1value = checked), then validate if textbox is not empty. If textbox is empty, then show validation error message.

How do I do this? Both checkbox and textbox are available as my model properties (bool and string respectively).

Is it possible to do this via a custom validation?

Comment: Use jquery validation for that.

Comment: I have other validations in my page for single fields as well. So, should I do everything in jquery or jus this custom validation? If yes, can you pls give examples?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a custom validator or  [`IValidateableOject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject(v=vs.110).aspx)

There's a good explanation of both options [here](http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/4/model_validation_in_asp_net_mvc).

From the link.
If you need to support client validation, then a custom validator is what you want.

If your validation is strictly server side and you want to validate a number of business rules at once then use `IValidateableObject`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch to [Foolproof validation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/foolproof/), which  offered this functionality through it's RequiredIfTrue validator.  I also really liked [Fluent Validation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation) since it was really flexible, and would also easily offer this functionality.  Foolproof client-side support is provided for each of it's validators, where the boundary between client and server validation with Fluent Validation is not as easily distinguishable.